# Node install error with node-gyp-build and a path on a drive that doesn't exist

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

### Background

I have a coworker I'm trying to help solve this issue. On a team of 3 they are the only person experiencing it. In short, they can't do an `npm install`. They get an error that looks like so (from the debug log).

```
info run @parcel/watcher@2.0.4 install node_modules/@parcel/watcher node-gyp-build
info run @parcel/watcher@2.0.4 install { code: 1, signal: null }
timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 59748ms
timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
timing command:i Completed in 280399ms
verbose stack Error: command failed
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\[name]\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v16.20.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:63:27)
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
verbose pkgid @parcel/watcher@2.0.4
verbose cwd C:\Users\[name]\[company dir]\[project dir]
verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
verbose node v16.20.0
verbose npm  v8.19.4
error code 1
error path C:\Users\[name]\[company dir]\[project dir]\node_modules\@parcel\watcher
error command failed
error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp-build
error 'D\[project dir]\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
error operable program or batch file.
error node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1029
error   throw err;
error   ^
error
error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\[name]\node-gyp-build\bin.js'
error     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1026:15)
error     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:871:27)
error     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
error     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:22:47 {
error   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
error   requireStack: []
error }
verbose exit 1
```

### Troubleshooting

Like I said, I do not encounter this issue nor does another team member. As a workaround, they have my copy of `node_modules` which lets them be productive for the time being. Here is what we've tried.

- We verified similarities between them and I's user and system environment variables.
- We cleared npm cache with `--force`.
- I had them install the C++ build tools for both 2019 and 2022 as [`node-gyp` docs](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) says it has an explicit dependency on it in Windows.
- We both have Python 3.11, but I also had them install 3.10 and add it to `PATH` even though I don't have it because it's the explicit latest version supported by `node-gyp`.
- We blew away their local node installation from `Program Files` and also from the nvm cache and had nvm reinstall it fresh. Testing `npm` after this appeared normal.
- Ran `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`.
- They also rebooted often between these steps.

I'm currently out of ideas. The super weird thing here is that the `D` path from the above error simply can't exist. There is no `D` drive on that machine. Further, the current working directory is reportedly correct and then suddenly changes.

It is initially (and correctly) reported as

- `verbose cwd C:\Users\[name]\[company dir]\[project dir]`

Then the path being used becomes

- `error 'D\[project dir]\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

And again it becomes

- `error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\[name]\node-gyp-build\bin.js'`

This makes me think some dependency isn't be registered properly so `node-gyp-build` is falling back to a search path from its own build environment that is supposed to be updated with the local configuration.

### Local Details

We are in a Windows environment, both using 11. Our systems are kept otherwise updated as well. As shared earlier, local node version is `16.20` which we are using in an `Angular 13.2` project. There was a recent bump from `13.1` as I had introduced `huksy` for pre-commit linting which works locally, on another coworker's machine as well as our github ci workflow. I would suspect that if it were affecting the other team member but alas. The project's packages are such:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^13.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@ngu/carousel": "^5.0.0",
    "@pdftron/webviewer": "^8.4.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-gauges": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-icons": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-navigation": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^11.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.6.0",
    "@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.17.5",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.0.2",
    "@progress/kendo-svg-icons": "^1.0.0",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^6.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "ng": "^0.0.0",
    "odata-query-builder": "^0.0.7",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "^7.4.0",
    "sass": "^1.62.1",
    "scss-scaffold": "^0.0.5",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.11",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.2.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.2",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.18",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.19",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.27.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.27.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-preset-angular": "^13.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
```

Any ideas on what's going on and how to fix the dependency/pathing issue?